# Magento,Front end is not working

Tags: magento

Magento ,Admin Panel is working fine. but Front end is not working.Only the landing page is fine, the rest returns **Not Found** messages.

Answer (score 3):

In the admin go to *System > Configuration > Web > Search Engines Optimization* and turn off rewrites. This will use the 'index.php' file for your site and if it works then you must have a problem with **mod_rewrite** - google for that as there are lots of guides already available on the subject.

Comment: Thank you very much. After lot of searching and testing only this worked for me.